# Forget my Keyring password KDE

Tags: network-manager, kde, keyrings

Every network related application ask my keyring password. But i am totally fool person who forgeted it. :( 
please help me. I can't read mail, couldn't access in firefox etc.

Comment: It is nothing but your Login password.

Comment: nope, my login password is not working here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

Comment: If it's actually the kwallet, not the gnome keyring, try http://askubuntu.com/questions/22154/how-to-reset-a-password-from-kwallet

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that you need either to remember that password or start over with a new wallet. 
This is how you start a new wallet:

```
  rm ~/.kde/share/apps/kwallet/kdewallet.kwl
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :(