# Get a KDE wallet password - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, password, kde

I was learning to install Kubuntu 16.04. The first time I did it, the installation was fine. I had it on my laptop. I reinstalled it again, but this time when I logged in the laptop, I could not connect to the wifi.

KDE wallet password is required to connect to the wifi, but I don't have it.
Any solution for this?

Noted: 
In this case, my default KDE wallet (kdewallet) is closed and unable to open, because I don't have the password.

Comment: You might also check out [https://askubuntu.com/questions/22154/how-to-reset-a-password-from-kwallet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22154/how-to-reset-a-password-from-kwallet)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by creating new KDE wallet.

To create new KDE wallet, follow this steps:
1.Open KwalletManager (search on start menu)
2.Use the menu item File → New Wallet in the KWallet Manager
3.Choose a name
4.Select first option "Classic, blowfish encrypted file"
[This will pop up after you choose a name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNHef.png)
5.Choose a password and verify it.
6.Now you should have your new KDE wallet.

To use this new KDE wallet, follow this step:
1.Open KDE Wallet (search in start menu)
2.Select "Different wallet for local passwords" --> Select your new KDE wallet
3.Apply
Now you can use your new KDE wallet password to login.

Follow this link to learn more how to create a KDE wallet.  https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdeutils/kwallet5/introduction.html